# React sessionStorage doesn't synchronize components

Tags: reactjs, session-storage

Hello I am currently struggling with sessionStorage and rendering Components.
When user logins, sessionStorage stores an id of an user to make the session lasts persistently unless the user logouts. And then, it redirect to the / and render App.js components.

if user logins, App.js should render the Header components with the logout text.
But it renders signup text and login text though there exists sessionStorage.loginId.

logout text comes up in the Header only if i reload the page. What should I do to make sure that there is no need to reload in a passive way to show up logout text?

My App.js code is below here.

```
import Form from './components/form';
import Comments from './components/comments';
import Header from './components/header';
import Signup from './components/signup';
import Login from './components/login';
import Logout from './components/logout';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './styles/app.scss';

function App() {
    const [ text, stateText ] = useState('');
    const [ user, stateUser ] = useState({});
    let sessionStorage = window.sessionStorage;
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Header sessionStorage={sessionStorage} />
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/comments" element={<Comments text={text} />} />
                    <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />

                    <Route
                        path={sessionStorage.loginId ? '/logout ' : '/login'}
                        element={sessionStorage.loginId ? <Logout /> : <Login sessionStorage={sessionStorage} />}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path="/"
                        element={<Form text={text} stateText={stateText} user={user} stateUser={stateUser} />}
                    />
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

And my saving an id of user using session storage is here:

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

const Login = ({ sessionStorage }) => {
    const emailRef = useRef(null);
    const pwRef = useRef(null);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const login_submit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = {
            email: emailRef.current.value,
            password: pwRef.current.value
        };

        axios
            .post('/api/login', data)
            .then(function(res) {
                console.log(res.data);
                sessionStorage.setItem('loginId', res.data.user_id);
                navigate('/');
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log('aaaaa');
                console.log(error.response.data);
            });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <form method="post">
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" ref={emailRef} />
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" ref={pwRef} />
                <input type="submit" onClick={login_submit} />
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

Lastly, Header component is here:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = ({ sessionStorage }) => {

    return (
        <div className="header_component">
            {
                sessionStorage.loginId? <Link to="/logout">Logout</Link>:
                <>
                    <Link to="/signup">Signup</Link>
                    <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                </>
            }
        </div>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1):

Session storage values need to be accessed using a getter method, not as properties of the Storage object.

So, in App.js and the Header component, you need to be using `sessionStorage.getItem('loginId')` rather than `sessionStorage.loginId`.